# File input not shows file name once it is hidden using v-if

Tags: javascript, html, input, vue.js, vuejs2

I am creating a vue web app, I have a simple file input, but there is some logic, due to which someone can hide or show the file input. Problem is once you hide the file input, and show again, it removes the file name. File name does not show while variable still holds the file.

Here is some relevant code and [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nv2reuge/) demonstrating it.

```
<div id="app">
  <button @click="switch1=!switch1">switch1</button>
  <div v-if="switch1">
    <h4>Select an image</h4>
    <input type="file" @change="onFileChange">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `v-show="switch1"` : this will not remove and create a DOM element

Comment: Yeah @SLYcee is right - `v-if` removes element from DOM since `v-show` only toggle visibility.

Comment: This is how any `input` element behaves that does not have a bound value when it is re-rendered. The problem with file inputs is there is no way to set them from Javascript (for security reasons). They are read only. That is why you cannot use `v-model` and have to use a `change` handler, and why the value disappears when you re-render based on `v-if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `v-if`, the input is not hidden, it's removed from DOM.

To hide an element, use `v-show` instead:

```
<div id="app">
  <button @click="switch1=!switch1">switch1</button>
  <div v-show="switch1">
    <h4>Select an image</h4>
    <input type="file" @change="onFileChange">
  </div>
</div>
```